# Creating composite for time-based performance task?

Tags: time-series, anova

I am trying to look at task persistence on math problems based on a motivational manipulation. So in this context, I am not interested in the number of correct problems, just the total # of problems completed as a measure of task persistence.

I want to take time into account however, because someone may complete more problems in less time or complete fewer problems taking more time. At face value these differences would seem to indicate individual differences in math ability, but as I am not actually measuring the correct # of problems as a primary outcome, I'm not sure how to approach this. I have not for example ever used a continuous performance task before and wonder if the setup I have has been done with those kinds of tasks.

The setup is:

9 optional math problems to complete as a function of motivation.

## of completed problems used as primary DV.

If one person completes 5 problems in 5 minutes, another completes 2 problems in 10 minutes, and another completes 5 problems in 2 minutes, what would that mean? I'm not sure how to create one interpretable metric that takes this into account. Should I just control for the number of correct problems when considering the total that were completed, and not address the time? Or is there a really simple way to create/interpret some kind of composite variable that I am just missing?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're concerned with effort rather than performance, why not use the time spent as your dependent variable, and ignore the number of questions answered?

There's a complication here in that subjects who answer all the questions are providing a [censored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)) value: you don't know how long the subject would've persisted had there been more questions to answer. But this concern applies pretty much regardless of your metric.

Comment: That was my original idea! I'm just going to add more problems and look at the time spent overall, which I think makes more sense. I just got caught up in the idea of potential controls. Thanks!